Why doesn't filter work in categories in Woocommerce?
I'm trying to create filter for products in woocommerce by attributes, but can't resolve error.
There is function to create container for filter before product loop and there is function for filtering. Why doesn't filter work in categories (/product-category/cloth/)? But works correctly in main shop page (/shop/):
function add_container_for_filters() {
    echo '<div class="filters_stn32">';
    echo '<h2>Filters</h2>';
    echo '<form method="get" class="filters_form">';

    // Get shop page
    if ( is_shop() ) {
        // Color filter
        echo '<div class="filter-option">';
        echo '<h3>Color</h3>';
        // Retrieve terms for color attribute
        $colors = get_terms( 'pa_color', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) );
        foreach ( $colors as $color ) {
                // Check if color filter is currently selected
                $checked = isset( $_GET['color'] ) && in_array( $color->slug, (array) $_GET['color'] ) ? 'checked' : '';
                echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="' . esc_attr( $color->slug ) . '" ' . $checked . '>' . esc_html( $color->name ) . '</label>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        
        // Size filter
        echo '<div class="filter-option">';
        echo '<h3>Size</h3>';
        // Retrieve terms for size attribute
        $sizes = get_terms( 'pa_size', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) );
        foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {
                // Check if size filter is currently selected
                $checked = isset( $_GET['size'] ) && in_array( $size->slug, (array) $_GET['size'] ) ? 'checked' : '';
                echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="' . esc_attr( $size->slug ) . '" ' . $checked . '>' . esc_html( $size->name ) . '</label>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }

    // Get current category
    if ( is_product_category() ) {
            $term = get_queried_object();
            $term_id = $term->term_id;

            // Query products in the current category
            $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                    'field' => 'term_id',
                                    'terms' => $term_id,
                            ),
                    ),
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // Store product IDs
            $product_ids = array();
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                            $query->the_post();
                            $product_ids[] = get_the_ID();
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata();
            }

            // Retrieve terms for color attribute present in filtered products
            if ( ! empty( $product_ids ) ) {
                    $colors = wp_get_object_terms( $product_ids, 'pa_color', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) );
                    if ( ! empty( $colors ) && ! is_wp_error( $colors ) ) {
                            echo '<div class="filter-option">';
                            echo '<h3>Color</h3>';
                            foreach ( $colors as $color ) {
                                    $checked = isset( $_GET['color'] ) && in_array( $color->slug, (array) $_GET['color'] ) ? 'checked' : '';
                                    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="' . esc_attr( $color->slug ) . '" ' . $checked . '>' . esc_html( $color->name ) . '</label>';
                            }
                            echo '</div>';
                    }

                    // Retrieve terms for size attribute present in filtered products
                    $sizes = wp_get_object_terms( $product_ids, 'pa_size', array( 'hide_empty' => true ) );
                    if ( ! empty( $sizes ) && ! is_wp_error( $sizes ) ) {
                            echo '<div class="filter-option">';
                            echo '<h3>Size</h3>';
                            foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {
                                    $checked = isset( $_GET['size'] ) && in_array( $size->slug, (array) $_GET['size'] ) ? 'checked' : '';
                                    echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="' . esc_attr( $size->slug ) . '" ' . $checked . '>' . esc_html( $size->name ) . '</label>';
                            }
                            echo '</div>';
                    }
            }
    }

    // Apply filters button
    echo '<div class="filter-button"><button class="filters_apply" type="submit">Apply Filters</button></div>';
    
    // Clear Filters button
    echo '<div class="filter-button"><button type="submit" name="clear_filters">Clear Filters</button></div>';
    echo '</form></div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_container_for_filters');


// function for filteging
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'filter_products_by_attributes');
function filter_products_by_attributes($q) {
    if (is_shop() || is_product_category()) {
        // Check if any filters are applied
        if (isset($_GET['size']) || isset($_GET['color'])) {
            // Initialize the tax query array
            $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

            // Color filter
            if (isset($_GET['color']) && is_array($_GET['color'])) {
                $color_filter = array_map('sanitize_text_field', $_GET['color']);
                if (!empty($color_filter)) {
                    $tax_query[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $color_filter,
                        'operator' => 'IN',
                    );
                }
            }

            // Size filter
            if (isset($_GET['size']) && is_array($_GET['size'])) {
                $size_filter = array_map('sanitize_text_field', $_GET['size']);
                if (!empty($size_filter)) {
                    $tax_query[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'pa_size',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $size_filter,
                        'operator' => 'IN',
                    );
                }
            }

            // Get existing tax queries
            $existing_tax_query = (array) $q->get('tax_query');

            // Merge existing and new tax queries
            $q->set('tax_query', array_merge($existing_tax_query, $tax_query));
        }
    }
}

